# Codeigniter 3.4 heroku deployment 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am currently trying to push a project to heroku, but I am consistently getting a 404 page not found error.

I have looked over my controllers to make sure they are capitalized, checked over my configuration file to make sure the correct base url is used, and looked at my routes to make sure my default controller was set correctly. I can't find why it wouldn't go to the correct controller.

My db code:

```
$url = parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));

$server = $url["host"];
$username = $url["user"];
$password = $url["pass"];
$database = substr($url["path"], 1);
```

My base url: `$config['base_url'] = 'https://fierce-coast-30613.herokuapp.com/';`

My route default: `$route['default_controller'] = 'Products';`

My inspector is giving `404 not found fierce-coast-30613.herokuapp.com/:1` as an error

Does anyone know a definitive way to deplor codeigniter to heroku or what I can do to get your assistance? Thank you

Comment: why is your default controller Products (with a capital P)? Have you tried https://fierce-coast-30613.herokuapp.com/products or https://fierce-coast-30613.herokuapp.com/index.php/products?

Comment: Thanks you, I adjusted my controller and it worked, alongside with my htaccess file. I ended up deploying it through elastic beanstalk afterwards.